# Can I run C# code in a separate process without crafting a console application?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .NET class library that has a class with a static method. I want my code to run that static method in a separate process - the same way I'd run it in a separate thread just in a separate process.

I know I can create a separate console application project call the static method from inside `Main()` but that's not convenient for my deployment scenario - I'd rather not carry an extra .exe file around. I know I can [use Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6813588/57428) to invoke it but that would mean being dependent on Powershell which I'd rather avoid.

Is there a way to run code in a separate process using .NET only? Maybe I could create the executable for that separate process during runtime?

Comment: Can you use a command line option to your existing app?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Should the process keep running once the initial one has finished?

Comment: @Gabe: Nope, my current code is a class library loaded into a surrogate.

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko: I want that separate process to run code that may hang - if that happens I can kill the process. I don't need it to run longer that the process with my initial code.

Comment: Would it not make sense then just to create a new app domain to run the task, and tear that down on failure, rather than launching a whole new process?

Comment: @Fergus Bown: I dunno. Will that reliably guard against code running an infinite loop?

Comment: Yes it will. AppDomains are bullet-proof against managed code issues. The only thing you can't protect yourself from is that you cannot tear down an AppDomain that gets stuck in a call to unmanaged code.

Comment: If it's a thread with no calls to unmanaged code then you don't have to mess with an appdomain - if the thread hangs you can kill it.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer - This is not true. AppDomains will separate only data, but code is shared. If there is an unhandled exception in any domain than the whole application will crash.

Comment: @OndraMorský Yes, but this question is about freezes/hang-ups, and not unhandled exceptions. It is true that you need to try..catch any call into the AppDomain to avoid a bubbled-up exception from crashing the main domain.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Unfortunately, you cannot `fork` in C# like you can in C on POSIX-compatible operating systems.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913120/fork-concept-in-c-sharp)

You have a few options. Since you're just looking to protect against infinite loops, you could just spawn a new `Thread` (a *new* one, not a `ThreadPool` one or a `Task` one). Then, you can call `Abort` on the thread if you need to kill it. This will trigger a `ThreadAbortException` in the other thread.

Your other option is an `AppDomain`. [You can create a new `AppDomain` using the currently running assembly relatively trivially.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb506139.aspx) Then, you make a call into a proxy object that actually exists across the domain. The proxy will use old-school .NET remoting to call the method on the real object (so no generic-passing, etc., since you're limited by .NET 1.1-based constructs).

Be aware that none of the above strategies will protect you from a crash in unmanaged code. Since AppDomains are a managed construct, you cannot use them to abort unmanaged hang-ups.

If you're really, really, *really* determined to get a second OS-level process, you can also generate a new executable assembly in a temporary file on the fly and start that in a new process. [See here for an MSDN article on new assembly generation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ffc3x75.aspx) Be aware that this is not trivial at all.

Comment: +1 for the terrifying idea of generating assemblies on the fly to run in a separate process.

Comment: @sharptooth Does this answer the question?

Comment: Well, I've found this great answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/826435/57428 about how to craft the console application at runtime. That isn't hard at all.

Comment: I know this is really old and am trying to solve this same problem but now in .NET Core. 
 That example you linked to does not start a new process and I believe that was one of your requirements?