# Multiprocessing in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, multiprocessing, fork

I want create a child process in C#, not a thread, which is derived from current process, been doing that in C on UNIX with fork(), and in C on Win with CreateProcess(), so does anyone have some example code for that in C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fork Concept in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913120/fork-concept-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-to-start-a-process-from-c)